# Linker error "undefined reference to SSL_get_peer_certificate" when building PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, cmake, openssl

I'm trying to compile the PCL 1.8 and get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10.1: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
```

If i list the dependencies of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5` I get `libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0`, which is `readelf -h /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep  Class\|File\|Machine'`:

```
Class:                             ELF64
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
```

However, I seem to have more libpq versions installed:

```
/home/t/anaconda2/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
/home/t/anaconda2/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2j-0/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
/home/t/matlab/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libssl.so.1.0.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

with `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` being

```
Class:                             ELF32
Machine:                           Intel 80386
```

And:

```
[ 12%] Linking CXX executable  ../../bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary
cd /pcl/build/io/tools && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/pcl_con
vert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -pthread -fopenmp       -Wno-deprecated -O2 -g -DNDEB
UG    CMakeFiles/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.dir/convert_pcd_ascii_binary.cpp.o
  -o ../../bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary -rdynamic -lboost_system -lboost_fil
esystem -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_iostreams -lboost_chrono -lboos
t_atomic -lboost_regex -lpthread -lpthread -lm ../../lib/libpcl_io.so.1.8.0 ../.
./lib/libpcl_common.so.1.8.0 ../../lib/libpcl_io_ply.so.1.8.0 -lboost_system -lb
oost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_iostreams -lboost_chron
o -lboost_atomic -lboost_regex -lpthread /usr/lib/libvtkGenericFiltering.so.5.10
.1 /usr/lib/libvtkGeovis.so.5.10.1 -lm /usr/lib/libvtkCharts.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/
libvtkViews.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkInfovis.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkWidgets.so
.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkVolumeRendering.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkHybrid.so.5.10.1
 /usr/lib/libvtkParallel.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkRendering.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/l
ibvtkImaging.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkGraphics.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.
10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltering.so.5.10.1 /usr/lib/libvtkCommon.so.5.10.1 -lm /usr
/lib/libvtksys.so.5.10.1 -ldl /anaconda2/lib/libpng.so /anaconda2/lib/libz.so -l
usb-1.0 -Wl,-rpath,/pcl/build/lib:/usr/lib/openmpi/lib:/anaconda2/lib: -Wl,-rpat
h-link,/usr/lib/openmpi/lib 
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_cert
ificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
```

Guess the /anaconda2/lib shouldn't be there?

How I can make sure that CMake links to the correct version (and remove the wrong version)?

Comment: You need to supply your Configure and Make arguments. You should probably post the CMake log, or the portion of interest.

Comment: Also, it might be good to provide a link to PCL.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to compile it removing anaconda from the PATH, and changing all values having a path to anaconda to lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ in cmake-gui

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but I to compile it removing anaconda from the PATH, and delete build file, then redo cmake, then make.